# How to process DynamoDB Stream in a Spark streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I would like to consume a DynamoDB Stream from a Spark Streaming application.

Spark streaming uses KCL to read from Kinesis. There is a lib to make KCL able to read from a DynamoDB Stream: *dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter*.

But is it possible to plug this lib into spark? Anyone done this?

I'm using Spark 2.1.0.

My backup plan is to have another app reading from DynamoDB stream into a Kinesis stream.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've been able to consume from a DynamoDB stream by tweaking: KinesisUtils, KinesisInputDStream and KinesisReceiver. The real change being in the KinesisReceiver where I use a _com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.streamsadapter.StreamsWorker_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this it to implement the KinesisInputDStream to use the worker provided by `dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter`
The [official guidelines](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter) suggest something like this:

`final Worker worker = StreamsWorkerFactory
           .createDynamoDbStreamsWorker(
               recordProcessorFactory,
               workerConfig,
               adapterClient,
               amazonDynamoDB,
               amazonCloudWatchClient);`

From the Spark's perspective, it is implemented under the kinesis-asl module in KinesisInputDStream.scala

I have tried this for Spark 2.4.0. Here is my repo. It needs little refining but gets the work done

https://github.com/ravi72munde/spark-dynamo-stream-asl

After modifying the KinesisInputDStream, we can use it as shown below.
`val stream = KinesisInputDStream.builder
    .streamingContext(ssc)
    .streamName("sample-tablename-2")
    .regionName("us-east-1")
    .initialPosition(new Latest())
    .checkpointAppName("sample-app")
    .checkpointInterval(Milliseconds(100))
    .storageLevel(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
    .build()`